# MUI makeStyles/useStyles hook with theme update not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a React project using MUI that currently has state for a theme (either light or dark). I am using the makeStyles/useStyles custom hook pattern in my component. I pass my theme state as a prop to the useStyles call in my component, but it does not update the component when theme changes. For example:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
    layout: ({ theme }: Props) => theme === LIGHT ?
        lightObject... : darkObject...,
    ...rest
})

const Layout = ({ theme, children }: Props) => {
    const { layout } = useStyles({ theme })

    return (
        <Box className={layout}>
            {children}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Calling setTheme in the component below (the parent of the component above), I assumed that because the parent component of this one changed state, it should have re-rendered the child. However, this is not the case. I found a "hacky" fix as shown below using the theme as a key:

```
// Theme, DARK, LIGHT are Typescript and Globals defined elsewhere
const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(DARK)
  const toggleTheme = () => setTheme(theme === LIGHT ? DARK : LIGHT)

  return (
    <div key={theme}>
      <Layout theme={theme}>{some child...}</Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When adding the key, I force the re-render. However, this again feels hacky. Is there a better way to do this? I don't really like using the ThemeProvider simply because this is a small enough app and I like to add a lot of customization and design specific elements. I also do not want to use the styled-components API.